# Bug with Toggle in jQuery

Tags: jquery, vbulletin

I'm trying to create a spoiler on a forum (vbulletin)
It's basicaly a toggle div on click. It's all working fine,
but when placing a toggle div inside another toggle div
the animation just goes up and down without stopping. (it opens and closes)

The weird thing about it is, when i test it on jsfiddle, it's working fine.

On vbulletin the jquery code gets replaced with BBcode like this

```
[spoiler] Text/Images [/spoiler]
```

HTML

```
<div class="head">
    Click to show content
</div>
<div class="body" style="display:none;">   
    Content
    <div class="head">
        Click to show content
    </div>
    <div class="body" style="display:none;">   
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.head').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.body:first').toggle('slow')
    });
});
```

Can anyone think of a solution for this?
Any help is highly appreciated

Heres the jsfiddle with toggle div within another toggle div
http://jsfiddle.net/9FP55/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your nested `.head`'s with `.body` you would need a more complicated selector:

```
$("div[id^=post_message] > .head, .body > .head").on("click", function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Of course the better solution is not to create this ambiguity to begin with.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/olizux/4/edit

Perhaps this is just a typo, but your code doesn't contain the required `$`:

```
(document).ready(function(){
  /* Code here */
});
```

Should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  /* Code Here */
});
```

Or simply

```
$(function(){
  /* Code Here */
});
```

Comment: You'll need to show the actual HTML you're dealing with then. The code you posted doesn't show "spoilers" within "spoilers".

Comment: Idk why, but your code doesn't seem to work on the forum at all. Theres no animation going on anymore i used it like that:  $(document).ready(function(){
$("body > .head, .body > .head").on("click", function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
});
});

Comment: @Sev The code works with the markup you're providing - I've posted test links to demonstrate this.

Comment: Yes, like i said it works on a normal html page, but not on the forum. Forum pages are php-pages btw, i don't know if that makes a difference

Comment: @Sev Check your code, your post above was lacking the `$` function name.

Comment: @Sev It shouldn't make any different it's PHP or not. Are these forums online somewhere we can see them?

Comment: Yes i've fixed the bug in my code already, fixed here now. And sorry, but the forum isn't accesable for public at the moment, it's online though

Comment: @Sev The code you have provided in the question works with the solution I have provided in my answer. Without further details, or access to the forum itself, we won't be able to assist in resolving this unfortunately.

Comment: Your code is being added multiple times. Lines 823 and 856 both contain this logic, which will result in the animation happening twice. You need to add this to the top of your page, after you have loaded jQuery. Also, you're using my old code - avoid that since you pointed out you have some ambiguity in your elements. Instead, use my newer code.

Comment: Oh :/ Any idea how to fix it? Cause the BB code [spoiler] automatically parses the jquery code

Comment: @Sev I'm updating my jQuery code above. Also, it appears you're adding this to a post template file, rather than the page template itself.

Comment: When i use your updated code, the animation stops working :/ (code is updated on the forum too so you can take a look)

Comment: You're using jquery 1.3.2. You need to update to the latest version.

Comment: Look on line 10, jquery 1.7.2 is included there, the 1.3.2 version is from a plugin i've installed on the forum. Could the 2 different versions cause this bug?

Comment: Line 27 overrides the effects of line 10. Both `$` and `jQuery` are mapped to `1.3.2`. If you want to use both, side-by-side, you'll need to use [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Does your plugin not work with 1.7.2?

Comment: It should still work, i've updated it to 1.7.2 now (don't wonder why it's still called 1.3.2 in the code, it's 1.7.2)

Comment: @Sev Nope, you're still loading `1.3.2` under `$` and `jQuery`.

Comment: Yeah i guess the old version is still cached (forum is using couldflare) i've overwritten 1.3.2 with 1.7.2 though and called it 1.3.2 so i dont have to to changes to the plugin itself.

Comment: @Sev The big hangup right now is 1.3.2. It's still being loaded. When that changes, my code should work for you, but you'll need to make sure it's loaded once on the page and not for every post on the page.

Comment: Ok it's now updated to 1.7.2, you're code works now but the bug still appears :/

Comment: @Sev It's not a bug - you're loading the code in multiple times. You need to load it only *once*. You need to load it before all of your posts - but after you've referenced jQuery.

Comment: But that's exactly my problem. The bb code [spoiler] [spoiler][/spoiler] [/spoiler] loads it 2 times, because theres a spoiler within another spoiler. I really don't know how to load it only once when having multiple spoilers :/

Comment: @Sev You don't load it with the BB codes. You load it on the .php page itself, at the top. The bbcodes will benefit from its presence by being on the same page - but don't load them together.

Comment: But how do i do that, sorry i dont really understand. It's a bit complicated because i have to edit it via admin control panel in a preformed panel where i can specify a replacement (the jquery code) for a BBcode (the spoiler tag)

Comment: @Sev Ignore the bb codes. They are irrelevant. Add this code like you would add a new <script> tag to your site. How would you add Google analytics? Or do you have direct access to the .php files?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11189/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-sev)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.head').click(function() {
$(this).siblings('.body:first').stop(true,true).toggle('slow'); 
}); 
});
```

Comment: with using .stop(true,true) the animation pops up and closes down again.

Comment: which version of jquery are you using

Comment: try to use simple stop() in place of stop(true,true)